# Semantic-UI, expanded table in segment (attached or not)

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I can't find in Docs if there is this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zIcna8yqlScotLwcZGX9

- **From this:**

[image: 1]

- **to this:**

[image: 2]

Code for StackOverflow policy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="ui container">

    <div class="ui segment">
      <p>Normal table in segment.</p>
      <br>

      <table class="ui celled table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
              <div class="ui right floated pagination menu">
                <a class="icon item">
                  <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="item">1</a>
                <a class="item">2</a>
                <a class="item">3</a>
                <a class="item">4</a>
                <a class="icon item">
                  <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="ui container">

    <div class="ui segment" style="padding: 0">
      <p style="color:red">Expanded table in segment, something like this:</p>
      <br>

      <table class="ui celled attached table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
              <div class="ui right floated pagination menu">
                <a class="icon item">
                  <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="item">1</a>
                <a class="item">2</a>
                <a class="item">3</a>
                <a class="item">4</a>
                <a class="icon item">
                  <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And StackOverflow ask me also to explain it better with more details. Maybe this is enough? No, it's unbelievable. Ok I go on. Again. And again.

Also now. It'incredible. Again, more text, more words, more power, more time. Thanks StackOverflow. many thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a built-in for this table in segment.

Comment: If you have managed to do it with css as it is shown on the second image, why do you need built in functionality? Also if you haven't found it in docs then most probably it is not presented.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: if you have some custom css and it is working then just use it. If it is nor working as expected then describe the problem more in details.